# The "X" plugin does not exist

Tags: 8, features

I've exported features in a multisite setup in site A, which I now want to import into site B. Though, I keep getting errors like:

- The "entity_embed" plugin does not exist
- The "bef" plugin does not exist

I've checked if the modules are enabled in advance, but still, I keep getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I've been short sighted: I've checked the existence of these modules through `drush en MODULE` assuming that Drush connect to the site basing on the site folder. It seems you now have to explicitly tell it to connect to a specific site: `drush -l SITENAME en MODULE`.